# I have a problem with write_excel_csv in splitting data frame and save the output

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following columns (Branch, Region, Sales, Stock)
that I need to split depending on the values on the region column so I generate data frames (a dataframe for each region).

I have used this code

```
lapply(names(s), function(nm)

write_excel_csv(s, "G:/19011/"+paste(nm,",",collapse = null)+".csv"  , col_names = FALSE, quote = "none", append = FALSE)
```

but it doesn't generate the files

Note:(it must be with write_excel_csv) because the other function of write.csv and similar ones can't encode the arabic language

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you able to post the errors you are getting?

Comment: Could you also include a representative small sample dataframe of your data? use `dput()`. This will help us help you. Have you looked at this link? [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `gapminder::gapminder` as example dataset and `purrr::iwalk` this can been achieved like so:

```
s <- gapminder::gapminder 
s <- split(s, s$continent)

purrr::iwalk(s, ~ readr::write_excel_csv(.x, paste0("G:/19011/", .y, ".csv") , col_names = FALSE, quote = "none", append = FALSE))
```